# Primefaces slider to change dates

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a requirement to show a slider that changes dates and shows the selected date in a label.
This slider should have a start and end date so the user can only change between the two, and a step of one day.

```
<h:outputText value="Selected Date: " />
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{myBean.sliderValue}" >
    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="#{myBean.dateTimeFormatSeconds}"/>
</h:outputText>
<h:inputHidden id="hiddenDateSliderValue" value="#{myBean.sliderValue}" />
<p:slider for="hiddenDateSliderValue" min="#{myBean.sliderMinValue}" max="#{myBean.sliderMaxValue}" step="#{myBean.sliderStepValue}">
    <p:ajax event="slideEnd" listener="#{myBean.onSlideEnd}" />
</p:slider>
```

The code I wrote is simple but only works with int values. Does anyone know how to use either long or Date values with p:slider?The code I wrote is simple but only works with int values. Does anyone know how to use either long or Date values with p:slider?

```
public void onSlideEnd(SlideEndEvent event) {
    event.getValue();
    //The above code returns int, I need long or Date so one of the lines below may work.
    //Date theDate = event.getValue();
    //Date theDate = new Date(event.getValue());
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use instead a [`<p:calendar>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml). `<p:slider>` is not meant for that.

Comment: @Tiny Thanks, I know what a `<p:calendar>` is, but I need a slider... If I can't do it with primefaces, there must be another way...

Comment: Have you tried parsing the result: Date theDate = Long.valueOf(event.getValue)?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to make your own slider plugin or take a look to this http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/

Answer (score -2):

I used this (no date stepping, sorry). As noted below, this is for PrimeNg, not Primefaces. The javascript should still work :

```
 <p-slider [(ngModel)]="cursornum" [min]="cursormin" [max]="cursormax" (onChange)="cursorChange($event)" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" ></p-slider>
```

and

```
this.cursormin = new Date().getTime();  //get milliseconds for slider min
this.cursormax = new Date(y, m, d).getTime();//get milliseconds for slider max
this.cursornum = new Date(n.getFullYear(), m + 3, d).getTime();//get milliseconds for slider cursor three months from now
```

with:

```
cursorChange(e) {
    this.cursornum = e.value; //get new milliseconds
    this.cursor = new Date(e.value).toDateString(); //convert to date and show as string
}
```

Comment: This is for PrimeNG not PrimeFaces

Comment: So? It still provides a guide to use the slider for dates. The javascript and method will work regardless.